# TypeError: errors.map is not a function even when showing errors conditionally

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to loop through an errors array only if there are errors. When there are no errors I am getting the TypError message about map. Side note: I know it's bad practice to use the index as a key but my errors returned from the server for form validation don't have their own unique mongo ID's.

```
      {errors && (
        <div className="server_error">
          {errors.map((error, index) => (
            <span key={index}>{error}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your errors are in an array, even an empty array would trigger this because empty arrays are still truthy. If you are sure it'll be an array you can add this condition to it.

```
errors && errors.length && your code
```

And this'll work.